# Reactjs - Handler router access

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I start with `reactjs` using `reduxjs` and `react-router-dom`

I have some route like `main/route-1`, `main/route-2` ... And i want to call some api to get data in each router when user `access` or `refresh`. have any way to hanlder access router url to call special api with that router ? what best way to do that thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way that you cant call API through the router. But you can call API when component loading. use `axios` to call the API inside the `componentWillMount()` function.

Edit: After I look again in [documantation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) they mentioned that `componentWillMount` method is considered as legacy and don't use it. So you cant use `componentDidMount` it will call API immediately after the component mount. Their documentation also said that the componentDidMount is a good place for instantiating the network request.

Comment: yes i using axios, and i need to init state data in first time thank for nice suggest `componentWillMount` but why not `constructor `?

Comment: @DeLe Yes, You can use `constructor` instead of `componentWillMount`. Thanks to you I watch the documentation and they say `componentWillMount` is deprecated and so you can probably use `componentDidMount`. It will call axios immediately after loading the component.